# Ionic 4 App uploaded to app Store with warnings

Tags: ionic-framework, app-store, warnings, transform

After upgrade my app to Ionic 4, I always get this warning when uploading the app to app-store:

***The app references non-public selectors in Payload|\app-name.app/app-name: transform***

I've upgraded every component, downgraded new ones, and warning is always there....

Is there a way to know what plugin / component is causing it ???

Thanks you very much, and sorry for my english

Comment: It was a proble of x-social-sharing pluging.

Comment: Are you able to sort it out?